# How to interpret this call stack information

Tags: c++, access-violation, callstack, exception-code

Can someone help me understand this structure of call stack?

MintControl::MintDIB::**MintDIB+22** in this statement in the below callstack, what does this number 22 means? Is it line number or some more critical information?

When ever, I get the crash log, these numbers next to method name are always same. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION
Fault address:  B821CD09 00:00000000 

Call stack:
Address   Frame
B821CD09  0012D088  0000:00000000 
0164E75A  0012D0A4  MintControl::MintDIB::MintDIB+22
01656E31  0012D154  MintControl::MintProjectorManager::getState+1E45
016593E7  0012D1EC  MintControl::MintProjectorManager::getState+43FB
01659353  0012D200  MintControl::MintProjectorManager::getState+4367
015BEB75  0012D248  LookAndFeel::ImageTheater::getImageBehaviorInterface+1E8B
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: This is platform specific, you should mention what you're using. How are you generating the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the offset in bytes from the start of the `MintDIB` constructor.

Primary suspects for causing the crash: calling an uninitialised or corrupted function pointer or calling a virtual member function in an uninitialised or corrupted object.